# Comparing a previously taken screenshot to a new one taking using the Robot class

Tags: java, ios, graphics, compare, screenshot

I'm trying to constantly test to see if my current screen matches a previously saved screenshot. What I have so far is this:

```
while( (timer - System.currentTimeMillis()) <= duration)
{
   robot.createScreenCapture(cScreen);
}
```

cScreen being a Rectangle class instantiation.

How do I call a screenshot and compare it to this? (I assume that comparing would just be [other_screenshot].equals(cScreen) or vice versa

Comment: What does "compare" mean in this context?  A pixel-by-pixel comparison?  If the screenshot includes the clock and the time has changed, is the screen shot different?

Comment: *"I assume that "* - generally speaking, no, you'd only be comparing the memory references.  Instead, you'd need to get the pixel buffer and probably do a manual comparison pixel by pixel